# NVDA Screen Reader Only reads Title Window in wpf Applicaton and not the whole page

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, screen-readers, nvda

I have created a sample application in wpf(.NET 5.0) which has textblocks.I want my nvda screen reader to readout the text elements as soon as I open my application.I have also set the Automation properties Name. I dont want to change the UX by pressing tabs to navigate between text items and then to focus them. Any help would be appriciated

```
<Window x:Class="samplejaws.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock x:Name="myTextBlock" 
                   Text="Welcome to My Application"
                   AutomationProperties.Name="Welcome Message"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"  />
        
    </Grid>
</Window>
```